# Disabling JTAG PINS on STM32f103RCT6

Tags: c, cpu-registers, stm32cubeide, jtag, stm32f1

In my newest project with STM32f103rct6 I have to use all Pins, including JTAG ones. I've checked reference manual, I know I have to deal with AFIO registers. So to completely disable JTAG pins, I have to write 100 on `SWJ_CFG[2:0]` which is the bit 24,25 and 26 on `AFIO->MAPR` register. So I coded:

```c
AFIO->MAPR|=(1<<25);
AFIO->MAPR&=~(1<<24);
AFIO->MAPR&=~(1<<23);
```

The problem is after doing this the console on CUBEIDE shows:

```
Target is not responding, retrying...
```

What Am I doing wrong? I have to use all PA13,14,15 and PB3,4 Pins.
Any help would be appreciated!

I checked Reference manual it didn't work.

Comment: If the IDE is using JTAG to communicate with the device and you disable JTAG, the IDE will no longer be able to communicate with the device and report an error. You may well be doing nothing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You basically want to use JTAG pins without using the JTAG pins. You will run out of luck with that.

Comment: hey guys. thanks for your answers. I did it. Basically you need to enable clock to your AFIO register. after that you need to write 100 in Swj_CG to rekease all your pins. at the End just remap all those free pins to their alternate function. There was a ULN on the way of my output which caused issue. after replacing it everything work out fine! I programmed my device using Hattel programmer with the hex file.